# Create New Dictionary On Every Button Press

Tags: c#, .net, dictionary, c#-4.0

I am performing calculations for all numbers between a start value and an end value on a user form.  My issue is that often times the user will need to calculate the same values and either extend the start or extend the end point, and in doing such will throw the error

> An item with the same key has already been added

This is my syntax - what do I need to alter to remove this error?

```cs
public partial class Test
{
    Dictionary<int, double[]> dictionary = new Dictionary<int, double[]>();

    private void btnCalculate_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        int start = txtStart.Text;
        int end = Convert.ToInt32(txtEnd.Text)+1;

        int[] ag = Enumerable.Range(start, end - start).ToArray();

        foreach (int a in ag)
        {
            dictionary.Add(a, new double[] { a*10, a*15, a*20 });
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: If you generate those values every time the button is pressed, have you considered clearing the dictionary (i.e. dictionary.Clear()) first? Dictionary.Add() throws when the key already exists. If you use the index syntax, then the previous value is overridden/replaced with no exception.

Comment: Dictionary.Clear(); such a simple solution!

Comment: Did that solve it? I can enter it as an answer. EDIT: Too late, others have entered that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can either clear the `Dictionary<int, double[]>` or check if the key already exists before you add:

```
public partial class Test
{
    Dictionary<int, double[]> dictionary = new Dictionary<int, double[]>();

   private void btnCalculate_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
   {
       dictionary.Clear();

       int start = txtStart.Text;
       int end = Convert.ToInt32(txtEnd.Text)+1;

       int[] ag = Enumerable.Range(start, end - start).ToArray();

       foreach (int a in ag)
       {
           dictionary.Add(a, new double[] { a*10, a*15, a*20 });
       }
   }
}
```

or:

```
public partial class Test
{
    Dictionary<int, double[]> dictionary = new Dictionary<int, double[]>();

   private void btnCalculate_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
   {
       int start = txtStart.Text;
       int end = Convert.ToInt32(txtEnd.Text)+1;

       int[] ag = Enumerable.Range(start, end - start).ToArray();

       foreach (int a in ag)
       {
           if(!dictionary.ContainsKey(a))
               dictionary.Add(a, new double[] { a*10, a*15, a*20 });
       }
   }
}
```

I don't know exactly what your use-case is, but this should solve your problem

Answer (score 0):

Ensure that you are not reusing the same `key` twice in your `Dictionary`.

The `Dictionary` class requires a `key` and a `value`, and the `key` must always be unique. The `value` property doesn't need to be unique, only the `key`.

This is allowed:

```cs
dictionary.Add(1, new double[] {10, 12.5, 7})
dictionary.Add(2, new double[] {1, 14.5, 2})
```

This is *not* allowed

```cs
dictionary.Add(1, new double[] {10, 12.5, 7})
dictionary.Add(1, new double[] {1, 14.5, 2})
```